# Get Information about Inserted Rows during a BULK INSERT

Tags: sql-server, triggers, bulkinsert

I insert information into my table using a *Bulk Insert* to speed things up. Now I want to add a trigger to my table. But this trigger is *run once with every Bulk Insert* whereas I need to know what the rows that were inserted are during the latest bulk insert.

So, is there a query to know what the inserted rows during `BULK INSERT` were?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an `ID IDENTITY` column, you could make a note of the ID before the `BULK INSERT` and then all rows with an `ID` higher than this value you wrote down have been bulk inserted.

You cannot have triggers on a *per-row* basis in SQL Server, nor can you do anything else (like using an `OUTPUT` statement) to capture the inserted rows, really. You just have to look at what's in the database before and after the `BULK INSERT`